# javafx add additional action to button

Tags: java, button, javafx

can you help me with this problem?

I create button in class `Cell` and add some default action to this button.

```
public class Cell {
    private Button button;

    public Cell() {
        this.button = new Button();
        this.button.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Default action"));
    }

    public Button getButton() {
        return button;
    }
}
```

In class `Game` I want add additional action to this button but I want keep default action either.

```
public class Game {

    public Game(Button button) {
        // this add new action to button but delete previous one
        // I want use both actions
        button.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("additional action"));
    }
}
```

I know that new action override previous action. So if I click the button it will only print `additional action`.

```
public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Cell cell = new Cell();
        Button button = cell.getButton();
        Game game = new Game(button);
        VBox vBox = new VBox(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Is it possible add new action to button and keep previous acction too ?

Comment: what are trying to achieve? if you want both action why not writing that in a single action??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the current action before setting the new one and invoke both the old one and the new one:

```
public Game(Button button) {
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> current = button.getOnAction();
    button.setOnAction(e -> {
        current.handle(e);
        System.out.println("additional action");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

JavaFX has built in support for attaching multiple handlers to an event. Check the documentation for [`addEventHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventHandler-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-) and [`setEventHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setEventHandler-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-) (which gets called when you call any `setOn` prefixed method). One thing to keep in mind is that the handler attached with `addEventHandler` will be triggered before `setOn` method i.e. the handler attached with `setOnAction` will be triggered last. You can change your `Game` to the following:

```
public class Game {

  public Game(Button button) {
    // this add new action to button but delete previous one
    // I want use both actions
    button.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, e -> System.out.println("additional action"));
  }

}
```